# Crash on rotation with modal segues

Tags: ios, swift, rotation, modalviewcontroller, uideviceorientation

I have view controllers 1, 2 and 3 chained like this, 2 and 3 are presented with modal segues:[image]

When the user has been in landscape mode for a little while (inconsistent time), unwinds to the parent view, and then rotates the phone back to portrait, the app crashes with these symbolicated crash reports:

**3 unwinds to 2:**

> Terminating app due to an uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSConcreteMutableData
>   rotatesOnDeviceRotation]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x19360600'

```
Last Exception Backtrace
0   CoreFoundation  0x297a1fef  __exceptionPreprocess + 127
1   libobjc.A.dylib 0x37a53c8b  objc_exception_throw + 39
2   CoreFoundation  0x297a7409  __methodDescriptionForSelector + 1
3   CoreFoundation  0x297a5327  ___forwarding___ + 715
4   CoreFoundation  0x296d4e78  __forwarding_prep_0___ + 24
5   Retrostock v2   0x28b293    0x28b28f
6   CoreFoundation  0x29759e09  __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 13
7   CoreFoundation  0x296b4515  _CFXNotificationPost + 1785
8   Foundation  0x2a415749  -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 73
9   UIKit   0x2cdf78b7  -[UIDevice setOrientation:animated:] + 319
10  UIKit   0x2cdf766b  -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1599
11  UIKit   0x2cdf6f69  -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 73
12  Retrostock v2   0x1ef675    -[IBGMethodSwizzler sendEvent:] (IBGMethodSwizzler.m:103)
13  Retrostock v2   0x1a850b    uvSendEvents (UVManager.m:162)
14  UIKit   0x2ce5cc81  _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 633
15  GraphicsServices    0x30f927d1  _PurpleEventCallback + 529
16  GraphicsServices    0x30f9241b  PurpleEventCallback + 35
17  CoreFoundation  0x297677cb  __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 35
18  CoreFoundation  0x29767767  __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 347
19  CoreFoundation  0x29765d69  __CFRunLoopRun + 1609
20  CoreFoundation  0x296b2201  CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 477
21  CoreFoundation  0x296b2013  CFRunLoopRunInMode + 107
22  GraphicsServices    0x30f91201  GSEventRunModal + 137
23  UIKit   0x2ce56a59  UIApplicationMain + 1441
24  Retrostock v2   0x169690    main () (AppDelegate.swift:14)
25  libdyld.dylib   0x37fdfaaf  start + 3

Crashed Thread 0 :
    0   CoreFoundation  0x297a231f  __handleUncaughtException + 631
    1   libobjc.A.dylib 0x37a53f13  objc_terminate() + 175
    2   libc++abi.dylib 0x37388de3  std::__terminate() + 79
    3   libc++abi.dylib 0x373888af  __cxa_rethrow + 103
    4   libobjc.A.dylib 0x37a53dd3  objc_exception_rethrow + 43
    5   CoreFoundation  0x296b229d  CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 633
    6   CoreFoundation  0x296b2013  CFRunLoopRunInMode + 107
    7   GraphicsServices    0x30f91201  GSEventRunModal + 137
    8   UIKit   0x2ce56a59  UIApplicationMain + 1441
    9   Retrostock v2   0x169690    main () (AppDelegate.swift:14)
    10  libdyld.dylib   0x37fdfaaf  start + 3
```

**2 unwinds to 1:**

> Application crashed with signal SIGSEGV

```
0   Retrostock v2   0x232293    0x23228f
1   CoreFoundation  0x29759e09  __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 13
2   CoreFoundation  0x296b4515  _CFXNotificationPost + 1785
3   Foundation  0x2a415749  -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 73
4   UIKit   0x2cdf78b7  -[UIDevice setOrientation:animated:] + 319
5   UIKit   0x2cdf766b  -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1599
6   UIKit   0x2cdf6f69  -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 73
7   Retrostock v2   0x196675    -[IBGMethodSwizzler sendEvent:] (IBGMethodSwizzler.m:103)
8   Retrostock v2   0x14f50b    uvSendEvents (UVManager.m:162)
9   UIKit   0x2ce5cc81  _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 633
10  GraphicsServices    0x30f927d1  _PurpleEventCallback + 529
11  GraphicsServices    0x30f9241b  PurpleEventCallback + 35
12  CoreFoundation  0x297677cb  __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 35
13  CoreFoundation  0x29767767  __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 347
14  CoreFoundation  0x29765d69  __CFRunLoopRun + 1609
15  CoreFoundation  0x296b2201  CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 477
16  CoreFoundation  0x296b2013  CFRunLoopRunInMode + 107
17  GraphicsServices    0x30f91201  GSEventRunModal + 137
18  UIKit   0x2ce56a59  UIApplicationMain + 1441
19  Retrostock v2   0x110690    main () (AppDelegate.swift:14)
20  libdyld.dylib   0x37fdfaaf  start + 3
```

I get these reports from Appsee, because the app is now in beta testing, and I can't seem to recreate the error on my own device, so I'm dependent on knowing what the error is before I update it.

It seems like the app "forgets" what view it's in, and don't know what to rotate to. I would really appreciate it if you have any ideas or have experienced anything like this in the past.

**UPDATE 1:**

> v2/ShinobiCharts.framework/Headers/SChartBandSeries.h:42:57: Attribute
>   'readonly' of property 'orientation' restricts attribute 'readwrite'
>   of property inherited from 'SChartSeries'

Comment: So you have a modal view that presents a modal view that presents a modal view? I don't see a reason for unwind from 3 to 2 when that's what pop(dismissViewControllerAnimated) was designed for. An unwind generally is to navigate further back in a navigation stack.

Comment: @DCGoD No, only the 2 and 3 are presented modally. View 1 is the initial view controller.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not just using push? This is the exact scenario it was designed for. The only thing I can think of here without seeing the code is that the reference to the 2nd controller is lost after unwinding through 2 modals so when it tries to rotate that view it's crashing.

Comment: @DCGoD I'm sure I had a reason for it some time ago when I made the decision, but now I can't figure out why, so I'll change it back, do you think the modal segues are causing the problems?

Answer (score 0):

If the view hierarchy is this simple then you may be better off just using either a push segue to navigate then unwind. Without seeing the code one would have to assume the reference to that 2nd controller is lost so the rotation crashes when trying to rotate it (although I haven't experienced this).

Or just pop back one or 2 views simply

```
self.presentingViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
// Or to pop back 2
self.presentingViewController?.presentingViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

**UPDATE:**

Your issue is Shonobicontrols specific.
https://www.shinobicontrols.com/forum/shinobicontrols/2014/3/app-terminated-on-rotation-in-[schartcanvas-viewabouttorotate]

*We have recently fixed an issue relating to messages being sent to SChartCanvas after it is dealloced that looks very similar to the above issue. 
Version ShinobiCharts 2.7.3.hotfix2 might be worth trying if you are seeing this issue. This is available for download from our Portal.
I hope that solves the problem you have been seeing, but don't hesitate to get in touch if the issue persists! :-)
Thanks
Ryan*

Comment: What is the difference between unwinding and dismissing it?

Comment: Generally for scenarios that are 1 view deeper than this and where you want to fire an action. There's no need to overcomplicate the code so although an unwind SHOULD work in this scenario it is much simpler to just type dismissViewControllerAnimated and use unwinds for scenarios where you are over 2 views deep in a stack and want to unwind and fire an action.

Comment: What is the intuitive meaning? When you dismiss a viewcontroller you pop it off the stack, and when you unwind you do what exactly? Also, I remember why I didn't use the push segue to start with, the views autoresizing acts strange when I use it.

Comment: The unwind is doing the same thing as far as popping views off of the stack to a certain point. Both basically have a completion handler. The views autoresizing "strange" may be your issue then. I would have to imagine you're experiencing a constraint issue somewhere.

Comment: The only error I've got is from a custom framework I'm using: ShinobiCharts, but I've always assumed it was there because I force it to only stay in landscape-mode(3rd VC). I've added it above.

Comment: This is why you have to post your code you're working with. Your error doesn't match any results on google which tells me it's a scenario with something you are adding to your app such as that charting framework.

Comment: I would love to post some code, but there are hundreds of lines of code. If you could point me in the right direction of what to look for, that'd be great.

Comment: I updated my answer to the Shinobi forum which discusses your issue. Good luck! Hope it helps.

Comment: Just one more question: Do you know if using the UIModalTransitionionStyle with a push segue is good practice?

Comment: Generally you would want to stick with each design. Modal = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical
UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal
UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve
UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl.

Comment: So using it in combination with a push-segue won't result in any crashes/bugs just because it has the word "modal" in it?

Comment: I honestly have never tried it. It's usually a bad idea for countless reasons to go against Apple's HIG. You can always create a custom transition though if you have a better design for your model. From the HIG ("If you vary the transition styles for modal views in an app, do so in a way that makes sense to users.")